# How to check if a user exists in Radius Server

Tags: java, freeradius, radius, tinyradius

Good morning everyone,

I need to check if a user exists in a Radius Server. I am not sure if this question can be answered by the server (I am new to Radius).

I have a java application, and I am using "TinyRadius", in particular `RadiusClient` from [here](https://github.com/ctran/TinyRadius/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tinyradius/util/RadiusClient.java).

I could not find a function in the API of this client to answer my question. Basically, I have the username (but no password) and I want to know if the user exists and is still active.

Can Radius server answer this question? If "TinyRadius" does not have the proper API, is there another Java library that can help me?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Looking for same. Ihave .net client from which i can able to authenticate user. but don't know how to check user

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. We had to prepare a special script on the server (I mean, not using radius), to check if a user exists

Comment: oops. i have two requirement. Pass username and get customer attribute like mobile number. secondly pass mobile number and get username.
Looks like both is hard to implement or may be not possible